# Open OracleSpatial Layer via Ogr2ogr in C#

Tags: gdal, c#, ogr2ogr, oracle-spatial, gdalogr

I want to transport an OracleSpatial Layer to Postgis. From within OSGeo4W-Shell this works very well. But from C#-Console-App the DataSource is null but no error occurs.
Here is what I have tried:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ORACLE_HOME", @"C:\Oracle\instantclient_12_1");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TNS_ADMIN", @"c:\oracle");
                    
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureOgr();
OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.RegisterAll();
    
Driver drv = Ogr.GetDriverByName("OCI");
if (drv == null)
{
   Logger.AppendLogMessage("OCI Treiber nicht gefunden!");
   return;
}
                    
DataSource ociDatasource = drv.Open(path, 0);
if (ociDatasource == null)
{ Logger.AppendLogMessage("OCI Pfad ungültig"); }
```

In
*path*
i have tried:

- "user/password@SID:SCHEMA.TABLE"
- "user/password@SID"
- "user/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=styx)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl.xxx.local)))"

I have installed Oracle ODBC Client 12.1 64 bit.
My Program runs in 64 Bit and gdal_oci.dll is there. Driver is found without errors.

Where is my fault?

**EDIT:**
If I try this in path: `"OCI:user/password@SID:SCHEMA.TABLE"` I get the error `in <unnamed>`  in ogr_csharp

**EDIT:**

Maybe in my configuration is something false. I installed from nuget *GDAL*, *GDAL.Native* and *GDAL.Plugins*. Then I copied the gdal-directory to my output path *bin\x64\Debug\gdal*. In its subfolder *\x64\plugins* I also copied the OCI.dll and the ogr_oci.dll (64bit).
The driver will be found: [image]

If I delete one of this dlls an error occurs and the driver will not be loaded. But maybe I miss another dll for oracle oci?

Comment: Should you not prefix your connection string with `OCI:` ? Also when you say `user/password@SID` what does SID stand for ? As written is should be the name of a connection defined in your `TNSNAMES.ORA` file. That file should be in `C:\Oracle`. Is that the case ?

Comment: Sorry I noticed you did use the `OCI:` prefix without success.  Another question: have you added the bin and lib directories in the instanclient to your path ? And while at it, did you try connecting using sqlplus ?

Comment: I can connect via ODBC DataSouces (with the SID from tnames.ora), SQLPlus is not installed. And there is also no bin or lib path in the instantclient.

Comment: Let's clarify the terminology: SID means a physical identity of a specific database.  Like for example `sqlplus scott/tiger@localhost:1521:orclcdb` That however is no longer used, especially since we have multi-tenant databases. The common way of connecting is by using service names, as for example: `sqlplus scott/tiger@localhost:1521/spatialdb` In your example, that would be something like `sqlplus scott/tiger@styx:1521/orcl.xxx.local`

Comment: Then you have the `tnsnames.ora` file. This is a catalog of known connection strings identified by an alias. For example: ```spatialdb = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST=localhost)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = spatialdb)))``` You can then use this alias to simplify the connections by writing `sqlplus scott/tiger@spatialdb`

Comment: Or you can also directly specify a full SQLNET connection string, like for example ```sqlplus scott/tiger@"(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST=localhost)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = spatialdb)))"
```

Comment: OGR (or rather the OCI driver for OGR) allows all of those syntaxes.  About the instant client, you are right: it does not separate into bin or lib directories: everything is in the same single directory.  When you install instant client, you have a choice of packagings to download: the "basic" package has all the libraries you need. In order to get sqlplus, you need to download the "sql*plus" package: unzip it in the same location as the other bits of instant client. That will give you access to sqlplus from the command line (I assume you have your path set that way).

Comment: That lets you confirm that you can connect to your database outside of OGR. Note that you need to set TNS_ADMIN to point to the *directory* that contains your tnsnames.ora file (not to the file itself).

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind Thank you for making such an effort! I have now installed the sqlplus package and can connect via sqlplus. Its working with the alias from tnames.ora and with the full SQLNet connection. But not from code. I have set the environment variables TNS_ADMIN and ORACLE_HOME even in code. And now I also added C:\Oracle\instantclient_12_1 to my path. But no success.

Comment: So we are making progress: we now know for a fact that the connection works. One test I suggest is to set the environment variables (TNS_ADMIN) in the command line before running your code (and of course have PATH set to include the instant client binaries - but you should have that already)

Comment: Other checks would be to make sure your GDAL setup does include the OCI driver (ogrinfo --formats). And ultimately that GDAL works properly: using ogrinfo to check an existing database table. Or ogr2ogr to confirm the loading works.

Comment: One more thing to try: set the CPL_DEBUG env variable to ON. This should trigger a logging of all actions done by the ogr lib, including the drivers. That may help isolate what happens

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind Tried setting CPL_DEBUG and CPL_LOG and CPL_LOG_ERRORS. But there is no result, no output. Not in stdout and also no logfile will be created. I also tried Gdal.GetLastErrorMsg(), but this is also empty. Please see also my edit  for ogrinfo --formats